# Pyinstaller exe not working on another pc

Tags: python, tensorflow, tkinter, windows-10, pyinstaller

I am making pyinstaller build with the following command :

```
pyinstaller --noupx --onedir -p F:\todeliver --hidden-import=tensorflow --hidden-import=tensorflow.lite.python.lite -F -i "F:/todeliver/logo.ico" --add-data "F:/todeliver/download(1).png";"." --add-data "F:/todeliver/plus(1).png";"." --add-data "F:/todeliver/settings-21-32.png";"." bg_support.py
```

It is working fine on the pc I am making build on but does not work on any other device.

[These are the exact errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwhXc.png)

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: Errorrs are: Could not import dlls